# Forwarding packets from loopback interface with policy-based routing

Tags: iptables, routing, port-forwarding, tunneling

I have the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 10000 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff
```

which sets fwmark 4 on all udp packets with destination port 10000. I forward it to a tunnel (without any nat) with policy-based routing:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip rule
0:  from all fwmark 0x4/0x4 lookup 87 
32765:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 
[root@localhost ~]# ip route show table 87
default dev tunnel  scope link
```

Everything works correctly if the packet comes from a normal NIC (`eth0` etc.), but packets that travel on the loopback interface (`lo`, for example packets generated with `socat -u - UDP:localhost:10000`) seem to skip [the routing decision after the `PREROUTING` chain](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg), and get received by the local host (which in fact replies with an ICMP port unreachable packet over the `lo` interface).

Is this expected behavior? If so how can I workaround that? I need packets not to have different paths for different input devices, as I want to use `lo` to test my more complex iptables ruleset (that is, an extra rule with nat won't be a solution for me).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things involved here.

Output from the local box uses the `OUTPUT` table, not `PREROUTING`. `PREROUTING` is for traffic flowing through the box.

The iptables rule only matches when a packet is sent. When the client opens a connection, it has to bind to an address before a single packet is generated. When it binds, it picks the source address according to the routing rules, without consulting iptables.

When you test using `127.0.0.1` as a destination and it sends the packet, it tries to send using `127.0.0.1` as the source address, which by default the kernel doesn't allow to be routed.

If you fix that issue, you'll then run into another problem when the packet leaves the interface and has a source address the remote system doesn't know how to return.

Thus the solution is 3 things:

1) Add the rule to the OUTPUT table:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 10000 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff
```

2) Enable localnet routing with:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.$iface.route_localnet=1
```

where `$iface` is your tunnel interface.

3) Add a `MASQUERADE` rule so that source address of traffic leaving the interface is rewritten:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $iface -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL -j MASQUERADE
```

*Note though, that when testing sending traffic to `127.0.0.1`, you're still likely to encounter issues. Nothing is rewriting the destination address, so it's geting routed out `$iface` with a destination of `127.0.0.1`. The remote system is likely to reject this traffic.*

Comment: Uhm yeah I initially thought that your answer was completely missing the point because you mentioned the `nat` table, but now I see the problem is the difference between OUTPUT and PREROUTING (such a dumb error on my side).

Comment: Oh, well you are right, I did accidentally reference `nat` instead of `mangle`, but the same design is present there. I'll update the answer to reference `mangle`.

Comment: sorry, with the same rules and route and adding `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 10000 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff` (which I could confirm it sets the mark with `-j LOG`), still the packet is received by the local host. It still seems there's something special about `lo`.

Comment: I also modified my routing table 87 to have only `blackhole default` (which should kill all packets), still seeing the packet going through `lo` and receiving an ICMP port unreachable. I think strongly suggests that the table is not being consulted at all.

Comment: Oh, sorry yes. If you're trying to access `127.0.0.1`, you need to do more than this. This should work if you're using any other address on the host. The reason this doesn't work for `127.0.0.1` (localhost) is that this only affects packets once they get sent. IIRC, the application binds to an address before a single packet is sent. So it binds to `127.0.0.1`, which is unroutable. If you add a MASQUERADE rule, and set `net.ipv4.$iface.route_localnet`, this should work.

Comment: Still not working, and no difference when I use the global ip of my public interface as a destination (so packets travel on `lo` but without 127.0.0.1 as source/destination).

Comment: Also, I just checked again with `-j DROP` that a packet that is output on `lo` traverses OUTPUT, POSTROUTING, PREROUTING, INPUT. So the difference between OUTPUT and PREROUTING has nothing to do with my problem. It is in the route lookup, something is hardcoded when a destination address is of type `RTN_LOCAL` (I'm digging through kernel sources to understand better).

Comment: @LorenzoPistone Yeah, I forgot about multiple interfaces. The MASQUERADE & route_localnet thing works fine though. I've updated the answer and tested on my local system.